# Game with moving circle through obstacle in Javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, collision

I created a game using Javascript. It is a game where a circle which can be controlled by the mouse, has to navigate through moving obstacles similar to a maze. When the circle hits an obstacle, the game should stop.

When i tried the same game but with one obstacle, it worked. But after adding more lines of code to create more obstacles, the circle and the obstacle doesn't appear in the output. Also, the crashWith function isn't being called when the circle hits the obstacle.

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
    canvas {
        border:1px solid #000000;
        background-image: url("https://data.whicdn.com/images/223851992/large.jpg"); 
        }
</style>
<body onload="begin()">
<script>

    var gamePiece;
    var gameObstacle = [];
    function begin(){
        gameArea.start();
        gamePiece = new piece(10, "white", 20, 135);
    }
    var gameArea = {
        canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
        start : function(){
            this.canvas.width = 480;
            this.canvas.height = 270;
            this.canvas.style.cursor= 'none';
            this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
            document.body.insertBefore( this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
            this.frameNo = 0;
            this.interval = setInterval(updateGame , 10);  //for each frame 
            window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(n){
                gameArea.x = n.pageX;
                gameArea.y = n.pageY;
            });
        },
        clear : function(){
            this.context.clearRect(0,0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
        },
        stop : function(){
                clearInterval(this.interval);
        }
    }
    function eachInterval(e){
        if((gameArea.frameNo / e) % 1 == 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    //for circle
    function piece (radius, color, x, y){
        this.radius = radius;
        this.speedx = 0;
        this.speedy =0;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.update = function(){
            pieceContext = gameArea.context;
            pieceContext.beginPath();
            pieceContext.arc( this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
            pieceContext.fillStyle = color;
            pieceContext.fill();
        }
        this.newPlace = function(){
                this.x += this.speedx;
                this.y += this.speedy;
        }
    }

    //for obstacle
    function obstacle (width, height, color, x, y){
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.speedx = 0;
        this.speedy =0;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.update = function(){
            obstacleContext = gameArea.context;
            obstacleContext.fillStyle = color;
            obstacleContext.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
           
        }
        this.newPlace = function(){
                this.x += this.speedx;
                this.y += this.speedy;
        }

        //check crash
        this.crashWith = function(gamePiece){
            var collide = true;
            
            var otherleft = this.x;
            var otherright = this.x + (this.width);
            var othertop = this.y;
            var otherbottom = this.y + (this.height);
            var circleBottom = gamePiece.y + (gamePiece.radius);
            var circleTop = gamePiece.y;
            var circleLeft = gamePiece.x;
            var circleRight = gamePiece.x + (gamePiece.radius);

            if ((circleBottom < othertop) || (circleTop > otherbottom) || (circleRight < otherleft) || (circleLeft > otherright)) {
                collide = false;
            }
        return collide;
        }
    }
    function updateGame(){
        var x,y;

        for(i=0 ; i<gameObstacle.length ; i++){
            if (gameObstacle[i].crashWith(gamePiece)){
            gameArea.stop();
            return;
            }
        }
        
        gameArea.clear();
        gameArea.frameNo +=1 ;
        if(gameArea.frameNo == 1 || eachInterval(150)){
            x = gameArea.canvas.width;
            y = gameArea.canvas.height - 200;
            gameObstacle.push(new obstacle(10, 200, "grey", x, y));
        }
        for(i=0 ; i<gameObstacle.length ; i++){
            gameObstacle[i].x -= 1;
            gameObstacle[i].update();
        }
        gameObstacle.x -= 1;
        //giving co ordinates of cursor to game piece
        gamePiece.x = gameArea.x;
        gamePiece.y = gameArea.y;
        gamePiece.update();
        gamePiece.newPlace();
    }
 
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works for me, as long as the mouse is in a somewhat good position at start (didn't really figure out what "good" is here - looks like it has to be inside the window very soon after starting the code).

Comment: The only thing I could see in the output screen was the background image. Neither the circle nor the obstacles are visible.

Comment: [Video](https://i.imgur.com/0c0OStr.mp4) of what it looks like for me, when the mouse is in a good spot at start. Note that i get the behavior you describe when the mouse is not inside the window soon enough.

Comment: Ah. It's working now. Thanks!!

Comment: Debugging in chrome, my suspicions are confirmed: Before the mouse enters the browser the first time, there are no mouse coordinates, and calculations that use them all result in `NaN` - the collision detection then always triggers and immediately stops the game.

Comment: Is there any way to correct that?

Comment: The simplest way i can think of is to initialize the mouse coordinates to something, e.g. (0, 0): `var gameArea = { x: 0, y: 0,`. Judging from there being code for the speed of the gamePiece already, i assume there will be a spawn location anyways?

Comment: It was supposed to spawn at 20, 135 in the function begin. After initializing the coordinates, it works perfectly! Thanks, again!

Comment: Ah, yes, but the position is always set to the mouse coordinates, which do not have an initial value: `gamePiece.x = gameArea.x;` - the resulting update `this.x += this.speedx;` will then be `undefined + 0`, which is `NaN`. The way you do collision detection will always trigger for `NaN`s. If you want it to spawn at (20, 135), just use those as initial mouse coordinates aswell. Note that the way the game currently works, the game piece will teleport to the mouse when it enters the window though.